# Laravel - Path of page from which request was made

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-request

How can I determine the path of the page from which the request was made?

I have tried `$request->path()` or `Request::path()` but these two return the path on which request is going..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try this:

```php
$request->header('referer');
```

Also `URL::previous` will give you that `URL`, for example:

```php
\URL::previous();
```

**Update:** You may use this to send a user back to form on failed validation:

```php
return redirect()->back(); // You may use ->withInput()->withErrors(...) as well
```